# convert pandas dataframe column from hex string to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hex

I have a very large dataframe that I would like to avoid iterating through every single row and want to convert the entire column from hex string to int. It doesn't process the string correctly with astype but has no problems with a single entry. Is there a way to tell astype the datatype is base 16?

```
IN:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['1C8','0C3'], columns=['Command0'])
df['Command0'].astype(int)
OUT:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base10: '1C8'
```

This works but want to avoid row iteration.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Command0'])
```

I'm reading this in from a CSV `pd.read_csv(open_csv, nrows=20)` so if there is a way to read it in and explicitly tell it what the format is then that would be even better!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `apply`.

```
df.Command0.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
>>>
0    456
1    195
Name: Command0, dtype: int64
```

And  you can do this with `pd.read_csv` call using the `converters` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path.txt", converters={"Command0": lambda x: int(x, 16)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also found that as long as you explicitly tell it the base in the converters case you don't need to apply the '0x'. 
`df = pd.read_csv(open_csv, nrows=20, converters = {'Command0': lambda x: int(x,16)})`

Answer (score 20):

You can use `apply` as per [@Andrew's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37955967/9209546), but `lambda` isn't necessary and adds overhead. Instead, use `apply` with a keyword argument:

```
res = df['Command0'].apply(int, base=16)

print(res)

0    456
1    195
Name: Command0, dtype: int64
```

With `pd.read_csv`, you can use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

df = pd.read_csv(open_csv, nrows=20, converters={'Command0': partial(int, base=16)})
```

Answer (score 2):

The reverse operation (float to hex lossless conversion) would be:

`df['Command0'].apply(float.hex)`