# pandas dataframe.apply -- converting hex string to int number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to both python and pandas. I would like to know how to convert dataframe elements from hex string input to integer number, also I have followed the solution provided by: [convert pandas dataframe column from hex string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955856/convert-pandas-dataframe-column-from-hex-string-to-int)

However, it is still not working. The following is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace = True, header = None, usecols = range(7,23,2))
for i in range(num_frame):
    skipheader = lineNum[header_padding + i*2]
    data = df.iloc[skipheader:skipheader + 164:2]
    data_numeric = data.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
    dataframe.append(data)
```

the data variable looks like:
[data variable (type:DataFrame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFNvY.png)
also the console output in spyder:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvfLe.png)

the error happens at `data_numeric = data.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))`
and the error message is

```
TypeError: ("int() can't convert non-string with explicit base", u'occurred at index 7')
```

I had also try`data_numeric = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`
but all the hex number turn into NaN, which is not I want.
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Is the data you want to convert in columns or scattered throughout?

Comment: Does it work if you use `.apply(int, base=16)` on one column of `data` at a time, instead of on the DataFrame as a whole? That is what is done in the solution you link.

Comment: @wwii yes, it;s the data I want to convert. it's datatype is dataframe and all elements is hex numbers.

Comment: @EFT your solution also works for me! Thanks for help. I add an extra for loop on each column and it works well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assume we have the following DF:

```
In [62]: df
Out[62]:
     a   b    c
0  1C8  21  15F
1  0C3  B7  FFC
```

we can do this:

```
In [64]: df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).map(lambda x: int(x, base=16)))

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
     a    b     c
0  456   33   351
1  195  183  4092

In [66]: df.dtypes
Out[66]:
a    int64
b    int64
c    int64
dtype: object
```

PS `x.astype(str)` is done for security reasons - in case if some of your columns are already of numeric dtype

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!!! It works well, and your solution lead me to study more about lambda and map functions in python!