# Python pandas dataframe shorten the conversion time from hex string to int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My intention is to convert the whole dataframe from hex string to int. Currently I able to do it based on the answer provided at [pandas dataframe.apply -- converting hex string to int number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899626/pandas-dataframe-apply-converting-hex-string-to-int-number)

> df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).map(lambda x: int(x, base=16)))

However, it runs very slow especially when the dataframe is big. I saw an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855646/5057185 saying that the lambda isn't necessary and adds overhead. I tried to implement it but I got this error.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(path+temp_file, dtype=str)
df2 = df2.dropna()
df2 = df2.apply(int,base=16)
```

> df2 = df2.apply(int,base=16)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6487, in apply
> return op.get_result()
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 151, in get_result
> return self.apply_standard()
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 257, in apply_standard
> self.apply_series_generator()
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 286, in apply_series_generator
> results[i] = self.f(v)
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 78, in f
> return func(x, *args, **kwds)
> TypeError: ("int() can't convert non-string with explicit base", u'occurred at index POWERON')

I believe this error is due to the dtype of the dataframe is object instead of string and this problem is known and solved in the newer version of pandas, pd.read_csv(path+temp_file, dtype="string"). I am using the old version of pandas. How can I workaround this or any other method to convert dataframe faster?

Comment: Your code should work. Can you post the CSV?

Comment: Can you use the converters parameter of read_csv ? Not sure what version it was implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise processing:

```
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x: int(x,base=16))
```

Another idea is reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df2 = df2.stack().apply(lambda x: int(x, 16)).unstack()
```